# Align 6 elements at 1 line (Label+Input, Label+Input, Label+Input)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, alignment

I wanted to create a view that will capture user's input. I have many fields to be included. Basically I separate them into 3 fields at the same time horizontally. Here's the sample image.

[image]

I am using MVC 4 view with html. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your raw HTML:

```
<form action="">
  <p>First Name</p>
  <input type="text" name="fname" />
  <p>Middle Name</p>
  <input type="text" name="mname" />
  <p>Last Name</p>
  <input type="text" name="lname" />
  <p>Age</p>
  <input type="text" name="age" />
  <p>Gender</p>
  <select name="gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
  <p>Phone Number</p>
  <input type="text" name="fname" />
</form>
```

You can use CSS to style the page.

Check out this link. It utilizes CSS to create 2 rows ('walls') with 6 columns ('panels') in each row.

http://jsfiddle.net/chiperific/kFr4h/

If you want it all to be in one row that overflows, the tricky part is the margins to make sure it divides the row logically.

On the other hand, you can always use an [HTML table](http://www.back40design.com/blog/m.blog/83/html-tables-how-and-when-to-use-them)...

Answer (score -1):

The most easy way is create a table and place all of them into this table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
        <td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
        <td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
        <td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
        <td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If the user was going to choose this option I would suggest that they at least search more advanced table structures including table heads and column settings.

Comment: For example, here's a good site that intros the basics of html tables: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/tables/

Comment: Or this one: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/